# React Redux: Como mapeio dois objetos para cada componente filho renderizado corretamente usando mapStateToProps e mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: react, redux

Um componente filho é renderizado por map no componente pai... Via props, no componente filho, eu recebo dois objetos e gostaria que esses dados fossem renderizados no componente certo que é mapeado. Não tenho muita familiraridade com Redux e queria saber como cada componente carrega seus dados corretamente. (No cód abaixo ele só renderiza nos dois componentes os dados do banco que é passado por último no mapStateToProps e mapDispatchToProps)

```
class DashboardCard extends Component{

    componentWillMount(){   
        this.props.emailList(),
        this.props.bancoList() 
    }

    renderRows = list => {
        let result = null
        if (list.length > 0 ){
        result = list.map((em) => {
          
        return <tr key={em.id}>
                <td>{em.data}</td>
                <td>{em.saida}</td>
                <td>
                {em.sucess === true && <span className='label label-success'>OK</span>}
                {em.sucess === false && <span className='label label-danger'>ERROR</span>}
                </td>  
            </tr>
            })
        }
        return result
    }

    filterList = () => {
        const { list } = this.props
        let filterItemList = []
        filterItemList = list.slice(0, 2)
        return filterItemList
    }

    render(){

        if (this.props.title === "Email") {
            this.filterList();
        } else if (this.props.title === "Banco") {
            this.filterList();
        }
        
        return(

                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="box box-info">
                            <div className="box-header with-border">
                                <h3 className="box-title">{this.props.title}</h3>
                            </div>
                        <div className="box-body">
                        <div className="table-responsive">
                            <table className='table no-margin'>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Data</th>
                                        <th>Retorno do sistema</th>
                                        <th>Sucess</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody >
                                    {this.renderRows(this.filterList())}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({ list: state.email.list , list: state.banco.list })
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({emailList, bancoList}, dispatch)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DashboardCard )
```